# Why does a topology contains its basis?

Tags: general-topology

The definition of a basis is given as:

Suppose a collection $\mathscr B$ of subsets of a given set $X$ satisfies:

1. $\forall x \in X,  \exists B \in \mathscr{B}$ such that $x \in B$.
2. $B_1 , B_2 \in \mathscr{B}$ and $x \in B_1\cap B_2\implies\exists B_3\in B$ such that $x\in B_3\subseteq B_1\cap B_2$.

Then the collection $\mathscr{T}$ defined as $\mathscr{T} = \{U \subseteq X : \forall x \in U \implies \exists B\in \mathscr{B}\text{ such that } x\in B\subseteq U \}$ is a topology on $X$ generated by $\mathscr{B}$ .

Now let's look at the following example:

$X = \{1 ,2, 3\}$
$\mathscr{B} = \{ \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\} \}$,
$\mathscr{T} = \{ \varnothing, \{1\}, \{1,2,3\} \}$

Is $\mathscr{T}$ a topology generated by $\mathscr{B}$ ?  If not please elaborate the reason.

Comment: Just check that $J$ satisfies the axioms for a subset of the power to be a topology.

Comment: Exactly the sets that can be written as a union of sets that belong to basis $\mathcal B$ belongs to the topology generated by basis $\mathcal B$. Here that is the case for *any* subset of $X$. The empty set corresponds with the empty union. Also note that any element of $\mathcal B$ can be written as such a union hence belongs to the topology.

Comment: Please derive your logic based on the given definitions. I've com across those definitions at Munkres. So what'er is your argument...derive it from these definitions

Answer (score 1):

$\mathscr{B}$ does satisfy the axioms of a basis, and $\mathscr{T}$ is a topology, but $\mathscr{T}$ is not the topology generated by $\mathscr{B}$.

Since points are open in $\mathscr{B}$, any set is open, and the topology by $\mathscr{B}$ is the discrete topology.

Answer (score 0):

Take $U=\{2,3\}$, then whenever $x\in U$ there is some $B\in\mathscr B$ such that $x\in B$ and $B\subseteq U$. Right?

In general, a topology always contains its basis, since every $B$ in the basis is a subset of $X$ such that whenever $x\in B$, then $B\subseteq B$ and $B$ is in the basis.

Comment: How does your first line contradicts the example ? I've not taken the sub set $\{2, 3\}$ at all

Comment: @aroyc Asaf is saying that $\{2,3\}$ is in the topology generated by $\mathscr{B}$.  But you didn't list it as an element of $\mathscr{T}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a trivial case for requirement of basis. Unlike simple cases, I intuitively understand this as:
 Sometimes it is not possible to define a superset of all topologies of a space. 
Usually in case of continuous spaces, e.g. Set of all rectangles in a plane. 
In that case,  we need a basis to check if something is a topology. For each topology X, we can generate a corresponding basis with given properties easily. And this helps in identifying whether 'A rectangle is a topology in metric space X.'

Answer (score 0):

Let it be that $U=\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}B_{\alpha}$ where $B_{\alpha}\in\mathcal B$ for each $\alpha\in A$. Will $U$ belong to the topology $J$ as defined in your question? Yes! $x\in U$ means exactly that $x\in B_{\alpha_0}\subseteq U$ for some $\alpha_0\in A$ and here $B_{\alpha_0}\in\mathcal B$ matching the definition of $J$.

Conversely if $U\in J$ then for each $x\in U$ there is some $B_x\in \mathcal B$ s.t. $x\in B_x\subseteq U$. From this it follows that $U=\bigcup_{x\in U} B_x$. So it can be written as a union of elements of $\mathcal B$

These facts together show that $U\in J$ if and only if $U$ can be written as a union of elements of $\mathcal B$.

Applying this on the example in your question we find easily that *each* subset of $X$ must belong to the topology generated by the basis you mention. Note here that the empty set can be identified with the empty union ($A=\emptyset$). You are dealing here with the so-called discrete topology and the answer to your question (is $\mathscr T$ generated by $\mathscr B$?) is: "no".

Notice that each element of $\mathcal B$ can be written trivially as a union of elements of $\mathcal B$ hence belongs to the topology generated by $\mathcal B$.

Comment: I can't see the "easy" reason for which every subset of X has to belong to J. J is satisfying all the conditions given by the definition. Where is he problem ?

Comment: Every subset of $X$ can be written as a union of elements of $\mathscr B$ (e.g. $\{1,2\}=\{1\}\cup\{2\}$, $\{1,3\}=\{1\}\cup\{3\}$ et cetera) so must belong to $\mathscr J$ as is proved in my answer.

Comment: Checking on the definition in your question take $U=\{1,2\}$ and note that $1\in\{1\}\subset U$ and $2\in\{2\}\subset U$ where $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$ both are elements of $\mathscr B$. This tells us that by definition $U$ belongs to the topology generated by $\mathscr B$. However it lacks in your set $\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{1,2,3\}\}$.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get properly. In the example there is no U s.t $U = \{1,2\}$ more over all U in J (in the example) can be expressed as union of elements of $\mathscr{B}$ and tha's perfectly fine with the definition. The definition never says that arbitrary union of elements of basis set should belong to J

Comment: The definition in your question is missing a quantifier $\forall$. It should be: $\mathcal{J}=\left\{ U\subseteq X:\forall x\in U\exists B\in\mathcal{B}\left[x\in B\subseteq U\right]\right\} $.
The example that you mention in your question is simply wrong. If $\mathcal{B}=\{\{1\} ,\{2\} ,\{ 2\}\}$
then $\mathcal{J}\neq\{ \emptyset,\left\{ 1\right\} ,\left\{ 1,2,3\right\} \} $
but $\mathcal{J}=\left\{ \emptyset,\left\{ 1\right\} ,\left\{ 2\right\} ,\left\{ 3\right\} ,\left\{ 1,2\right\} ,\left\{ 1,3\right\} ,\left\{ 2,3\right\} \left\{ 1,2,3\right\} \right\} $.